# finding a basis where the quadratic form is determined by a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

1. $q(x)=q(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2+x_2^2+4x_3^2+4x_1x_2+10x_2x_3+2x_1x_3$ is a quadratic form over $\mathbb{R^3,a\in R}$.

a. find the rank and the signature of $q(x)$.

b. is there a basis where $q(x)$ is determined by the matrix \begin{bmatrix}3&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&1+a^2\end{bmatrix}
c. find the maximum dimension subspace $\mathbb{U}$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$ so that $q(x)$ is positive definite.

I managed to solve (a) by getting to the reduced form of $q(x)$ which is $q(x)=(x_1+2x_2+x_3)^2-3(x_2-x_3)^2+6x_3^2$ showing that there are 2 positive components and one negative component and the rank is 3 (there are 3 non zero components).

I tried to solve (b) by using congruence matrices and trying to check if the quadratic form matrix in the trivial basis and the matrix given in (b) are congruent. We were thought of a method for checking it by taking one matrix and for every elementary row operation doing the equivalent column operation, if you can do a series of those operations, the matrix you started with and the matrix you ended with are congruent, and they represent the same quadratic form.

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\2&1&5\\1&5&4\end{bmatrix}

by those operations: $R_3\rightarrow R_3-R_1, C_3\rightarrow C_3-C_1, R_2\rightarrow R_2-2R_1, C_2\rightarrow C_2-2C_1$. I got to the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-3&3\\0&3&3\end{bmatrix} but I couldn't find a way of getting to the matrix given in the question.

regarding question (c), I think the maximum dimension of a subspace where $q(x)$ is positive definite is 2 (because in the reduced form we have 2 positive components squared (can they be zero though?)) but I don't know what is the method of finding such basis.

Thanks. Sorry for my English btw.

Comment: the matrix in (b)  is positive definite. Sylvester's Law of Inertia

Comment: @WillJagy Meaning it can't represent the same quadratic form because of the signature we got in (a) (number of positive and negative coefficients must be the same?)